# in vb.net is there something similar to "with" but for functions?

Tags: vb.net, function, with-statement

I use the same function over and over in a row, is there a way to just be like

```
with basicmove()
{(r),(u, 20),(r)
end with
```

instead of

```
    basicmove(r)
    basicmove(u, 20)
    basicmove(r)
```

EDIT: Or

```
        basicmove(l, 5)
    basicmove(d, 3)
    basicmove(l, 21)
    basicmove(u, 5)
```

Comment: you could write an overload.  `With` is for objects

Comment: As an option you can put the parameters to array and then call basicmove() in a loop passing an array element to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this addresses everything you are asking for, but maybe it will give you an idea.

**EDIT:** based on the updated question, I have another solution. This requires understanding of [two-dimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in programming. You just load all the "coordinates" into an array and then iterate them and perform the operations in the same order they are entered into the array.

```
Sub Main()
    ' multi-dimensional array of moves (there are plenty of way to create this object if this is confusing)
    Dim myList(,) As Object = New Object(,) { _
                                {"l", 5}, _
                                {"d", 3}, _
                                {"l", 21}, _
                                {"u", 5} _
                            }

    ' iterate the array and perform the moves.
    For x As Integer = 0 To myList.GetUpperBound(0)
        ' getting coordinates from the first & second dimension
        basicmove(myList(x, 0), myList(x, 1))
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub basicmove(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("param1:" & a & ",param2:" & b)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. But if the parameter is of the same type you could use a list of the base type and `List.ForEach` or a plain `For Each` loop:

```
moves.ForEach(Function(r) basicmove(r))
```

You could create a new class with appropriate properties and a `List(Of Move)`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the c# syntax.  This is untested, so there may be errors.

```
public class myWith{
public List<Object> params{get;set;}
   public with(Action<Object> function){
      params.ForEach(p=>function(p));
   }     
}
```

The idea for usage would be:

```
new myWith(x=>doStuff(x)){
    params = new List<Object>{r, {u,20}, r}
}
```

Hopefully this gets the idea across

Answer (score 0):

This is not the prettiest, though it works, using implicit arrays:

```
Private Sub MakeCalls()
    Dim r As Integer = 1 : Dim u As Integer = 2
    For Each o In {({r}), ({u, 20}), ({r})}
        basicmove(o)
    Next
End Sub     
Private Sub basicmove(params() As Integer)
    For Each i As Integer In params
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```